# What is this material effect called?

Tags: texturing, materials

I Was looking through some Nintendo files and saw this material: https://gyazo.com/2355e477339ffff99cd50c3e53483cdf

is there a name for that glossiness effect, and does someone know how to replicate that in Blender?

Comment: Looks like a material with a clear coat and a normal map for the surface irregularities.

Comment: But it looks so flat. Can a normal map actually look this flat?

Comment: Sure just plug it into the clear coat normal socket of the *Principled BSDF* and adjust the strength.

Comment: I will try that soon, thanks!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: the material is rather glossy, you can use a Noise Texture plugged into a Bump node plugged into the normal socket to have the grainy effect...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get this effect is by using a musgrave texture as a factor of the roughness input and use the same as the normal with a bump node in between [image]

Which will get you this:[image]

You can tweak the values if needed

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a physical based rendered plastic material. It's surface features likely come from a normal map, while the finer reflective details are likely a metalness and roughness map. Ordinarily you'd have to make it in Substance, but it's definitely possible with Blender Nodes and Gimp. What game did you find this in?

Comment: Mario Kart Wii, the cookie land battle stage. You can view it on a website called "noclip.website"

Comment: Interesting. That PBR material looked surprisingly modern, and certainly better than I would expect possible from the Wii.